# LinkSwitch-XT2 (LNK3696) with opto feedback

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

What's a proper circuit if I want to use a LinkSwitch-XT2 device (from Power Integrations) with an opto coupler in the feedback loop?

This is the typical application circuit of LinkSwitch-XT2 devices.
[image: Typical Application with LinkSwitch-XT2.]

The datasheet mentions that the current into the feedback pin should be limited to 1.2mA (see page 3 - Chapter: "Feedback Input Circuit"). How can I limit the current into the feedback pin??

Link to the datasheet:
https://ac-dc.power.com/sites/default/files/product_document/data_sheet/linkswitch-xt2_family_datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> How can I limit the current into the feedback pin??

Was this your expected answer? It was there in the same datasheet.

> *R3 limits the current into the FEEDBACK pin. A maximum current of 120% of IFBSD is recommended

[image]